# How will I make an If College is Check then this Course would be in the dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html

```
So I am trying to do an that If the College is selected in the checkbox then the college course would show like
```

BS-IT,
BS-IT-DA, 
BS-CS 
in the drop-down 
else if the senior high is check then the strand would show 
GAS, 
IT, 
CS. 
I don't know if it is required with the JavaScript or 
J-Query

```
<div class="form-group right">
     <label class="label-title">Status</label>
     <div>
         <label><input type="checkbox">College Student</label>
         <label><input type="checkbox" class="senior-high" >Senior High</label>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="horizontal-group">
     <div class="form-group left">
          <label for="">Course</label>
          <select  id="Course"></select>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to do that once you check College the Select id = "Course" would go the given course like the BSIT, BSITDA, BSCS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//first add id="collage" on collage checkbox and add class="checkbox" on all checkbox add senior_highcheckbox id on senior hs checkbox

```
$(document).on('click','.checkbox'function(){
 if($('#college').is('checked')){
    $('#course').append(`<option>BS-IT </option> 
                        <option>BS-IT-DA</option>
                        <option>BS-CS</option>`);
    $('#senior_highcheckbox').attr('checked',false);
 }else{
   $('#course').append(`<option>GAS</option>
                       <option>IT</option>
                        <option>CS</option>`);
   $('#college').attr('checked',false);
 }
})
```

Comment: How can you make it only check one checkbox? and it is not working on the college it only shows the Seniorhigh

Comment: ill edited it already check if it works on you. try different way there is so many ways to do what you want.. good luck dude

Answer (score 0):

I've amended your HTML slightly so I can find the ID with jQuery. What you want to do is to listen out for the checkbox with Jquery and then check its ID attribute. If the attribute is equal to 'college' then append the first list of items. Otherwise it must be the other checkbox so append the others.

```js
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('id') === 'college') {
    $('#Course').append($('<option></option>').html('BS-IT'), $('<option></option>').html('BS-IT-DA'), $('<option></option>').html('BS-CS'));
  } else {
    $('#Course').append($('<option></option>').html('GAS'), $('<option></option>').html('IT'), $('<option></option>').html('CS'));
  }
  $(':checkbox').attr("disabled", true);
});

$('#cancel').click(function() {
  $(':checkbox').prop("checked", false);
  $(':checkbox').attr("disabled", false);
  $('#Course').empty();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group right">
  <label class="label-title">Status</label>
  <div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="college" name="college">
    <label for="college">College Student</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="senior-high" name="senior-high">
    <label for="senior-high">Senior High</label>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="horizontal-group">
  <div class="form-group left">
    <label for="">Course</label>
    <select id="Course"></select>
  </div>
  <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: How can you make it only check one checkbox?

Comment: See updated code to see it check for just one checkbox. I have added a cancel button to remove them too in case you needed to.

Comment: @JmMacatangay has this worked for you? If it has, please upvote this answer or accept. :)